# Kafka partition rebalancing in spring for kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a micro-service which is using spring for Kafka consumer using `@KafkaListener`
with some group id. This application is deployed to the cloud with two instances in different regions.

So now i think the partition is divided among two consumers as they both have same group id.

Is there any possible way to assign all the partitions to a single instance. I don't want partition  rebalance.

How to create customised offset using ConsumerRebalanceListener in spring kafka application ?

Comment: It would help others help you  if you can provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: It's not possible for a single partition to be divided between consumers. But what's the purpose of the second instance if all partitions only are read by one instance?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set `partition.assignment.strategy`  property of the consumer to `org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.StickyAssignor`

It's stated goal is

> Guarantees an assignment that is maximally balanced while **preserving as many existing partition assignments as possible.**

I've personally not used it, but if I understand it's purpose correctly, if you start another consumer in the same group, there would not be rebalancing until that first consumer dies.